# regular expression not containing special word in java

Tags: java, regex

Input string

```
hello sworked? worked hello
```

output string

I need only `work` in `worked`.

I tried with this regex

```
(?!s)work
```

But this returns all `work` in both of `sworked?` and `worked`.

Comment: I do not unterstand what is supposed to be replaced by what.

Comment: Do you mean `\bwork`?

Comment: @Igor Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match `work` not preceded with `s` use

```
(?<!s)work
```

See [proof & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cMR3zH/1). `(?<!s)` is a negative lookbehind disallowing `s` right before `work`.

Or, match a word startign with `work`:

```
\bwork
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cMR3zH/2). `\b` is a word boundary.

Add `\w*` to match the rest of the word if necessary.

In Java, double backslashes (e.g. `String regex = "\\bwork";`).